# Регулярные выражения в google sheets

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть текст в ячейке google sheets:
**"В ноябре 2020 года компания вышла на прибыль. Напомним, что в марте 2020 года, компания показывала убыточность".**

Моя задача - заменить **"в ноябре 2020 года"** на **"11.20"**, и **"в марте 2020 года"** на **"03.2020"**.

По таблице:
Содержимое таблицы - только текст с числами.
Структура - классическая таблица с колонками.
Количество листов - 3

Я использую формулу regexreplace, но она работает только с конкретным выражением и с одним примером: =REGEXREPLACE(F761;"ноября 2020 года";"11.2020"). То есть на выходе получается:
"11.2020 компания вышла на прибыль. Напомним, что в марте 2020 года, компания показывала убыточность"

Таких ячеек с разными датами и форматами много, моя глобальная задача - привести их к формату мм.гггг, так как вся работа с доком ведется онлайн в google sheets, скачать csv и обработать в Python - не вариант.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность использовать в regexreplace несколько условий? Может, кто знает другие варианты?

Comment: 1. Так Excel или Google Sheets? Это разное ПО со схожим, но различающимся функционалом. 2. Какое содержимое есть в таблице? Только текст и числа или есть сложные формулы? И что по структуре, всё в формате классической таблицы с колонками или что-то неформальное? Сколько страниц? Сколько вообще таких таблиц?

Comment: 1. Работать буду в Google Sheets. 
2. Содержимое таблицы - только текст и числа
3. Формат классической таблицы с колонками 
4. Страниц 3 
5. Таблица одна 

Спасибо за уточнения, сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: Нет, нельзя, в Google Sheets нет поддержки условного шаблона замены в `REGEXREPLACE`. Делайте 12 вложенных замен.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя формулы вам надо будет подписать их к каждой нужной ячейке. Также это не заменит исходных значений в таблице и лишь её усложнит, либо надо будет все исправленные значения перекопировать вручную, уже без формул, только результаты. Это сложно масштабировать.

Предлагаю пару более элегантных решений.

## 1. Google App Script

Разновидность JavaScript, которая позволяет сильно кастомизировать Гугл-доки, и добавлять свои формочки, и значения программно редактировать. Можете написать скрипт с воообще любой логикой, в том числе заменой подстрок по любым правилам и регуляркам.

Материалы:

- [developers.google.com: Apps Script Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [developers.google.com: Apps Script in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [developers.google.com: App Script SpreadSheet reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [codd-wd.ru: Примеры App Script в Google Sheets](https://codd-wd.ru/shpargalka-dopolneniya-dlya-google-tablic-spreadsheets-i-ispolzovanie-google-apps-script/)

## 2.1. API и Python

Скачивать и перезаливать таблицу вовсе не обязательно, Google сервисы имеют мощное АПИ для решения почти любых задач в рамках этих сервисах. Можно легко написать скрипт на Питоне для считывания таблиц, выявления значений, которые требуется отредактировать, собственно редактирования по любой логике, и последующей перезаписи. В общем, то же самое, как это делает человек через браузер, только автоматизированно :) Также этим способом можно легко задавать на обработку как все, так и некоторые страницы в таблицах, и даже множество таблиц сразу.

Материалы:

- [developers.google.com: Sheets API Python QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- [habr.com: Начинаем работу с Google Sheets на Python](https://habr.com/ru/post/483302/)
- [pypi.org: gspread](https://pypi.org/project/gsheets/) – библиотека для более удобной работы с Google Sheets из Питона. Примеров по ней можно нагуглить массы.